# Jmeter thread-groups are not running independent for different users

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, load-testing

I have load testing scenario where test-plan has multiple thread-group and each thread-group has different type of HTTP request and this group is designed to executed in sequence .
Below is scenario I'm testing -

```
Test-Plan
 +---Thread-Group(Register-Request)
 +---Thread-Group(Container-Request)
 +---Thread-Group(Subscription-Request)
 +---Thread-Group(Data-Request)
 +---Thread-Group(Deregister-Request)
```

Load testing has to follow the defined sequence. Each user-thread reads thread specific values from CSV file and during testing, JMeter output shows that:

User-threads don't move from Thread-Group(Register-Request) to Thread-Group(Container-Request) until all user threads have completed execution which looks odd to me.

Any idea what could the reason of this behaviour ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User threads don't "move" from one [Thread Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74310636/kg-apc-jmeter-functions-fifotimeout-not-working-when-there-are-no-items-remainin/74312532#74312532) to another Thread Group, each Thread Group has its own pool of virtual users and they're not connected by any means.

So if you want each user to execute some actions (Register-Request, Container-Request, etc.) sequentially - you need to put the relevant [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) under the same Thread Group.

If your workload model is more complex and i.e. you need to run different scenarios with different throughputs and maintain user session across Thread Groups at the same time - you can take a look at i.e. [Using JMeter Variables With Multiple Thread Groups](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-variables) article  [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/) or